# JTable component access before row selection

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listselectionlistener

I'm using a jtable and i need to access a component locate in a row different from the selected one.
The problem i have is that when i click the component the row selection change come before the component click event.
This is a SSCE that explain the problem.

```
package test;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class Main extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
}

public Main() {
    JButton btnTest = new JButton("test");
    btnTest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.err.println("btnTest clicked!");
        }
    });
    JButton btnTest2 = new JButton("test2");
    btnTest2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.err.println("btnTest2 clicked!");
        }
    });
    JTable table = new JTable(new Object[][] {
            { btnTest, "test"},
            { btnTest2, "test2"},
    }, new Object[] {"btn", "desc"});
    table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, new Editor());
    table.setDefaultRenderer(JComponent.class, new TableCellRenderer() {            
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            return (JComponent)(value);
        }
    });
    ListSelectionModel rowSM = table.getSelectionModel();
    rowSM.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            System.err.println("new Selection!");
        }
    });
    table.setSelectionModel(rowSM);
    add(table);
    setSize(300, 300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}

class Editor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JComponent item;

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return item;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        item = (JComponent)value;
        item.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        return item;
    }       
}
}
```

When i click the button the row  unselected this is the console result:

```
new Selection!
btnTest clicked!
new Selection!
```

Is possible to fire the "btnTest clicked!" first?

Thanks

Comment: don't put JButton to JTable, XxxTableModel is designated to nest/hold only the value for Renderer/Editor

Comment: +1 for SSCCE, good, reasonable question, to try events from JButton that is rendered in JTables view by XxxTableRenderer

Comment: as aside to test !isAdjusting??? from two  ListSelectionListeners events

Comment: Ohh.. getIsAdjusting! Really thanks mKorbel, this method save me!